# How do I connect an issue on JIRA to a test case on Testlink?

Tags: testcase, testlink, jira

I have successfully integrated between JIRA and Testlink.

I haven't found yet how to connect from one issue on JIRA to its test case on Testlink. How can I connect JIRA issues with Testlink test cases?

Answer (score 5):

[www.slideshare.net/ErolSelitektay/test-link-jira-soap-integration](http://www.slideshare.net/ErolSelitektay/test-link-jira-soap-integration) and http://blogs.fcoos.net/integrate-testlink-with-jira/
give steps on how to configure JIRA on your Teslink.
Before you start, ensure you have Testlink 1.9.5 or above and JIRA 5.2 or above.

Test Link Screens involved:

[image]
[image]

The steps in the second link are:

1. Install and configure Testlink as per the documentation.
2. Create the project in the Testlink with relevant data.
3. After the creation of the project, then select the project, go to  Issue Tracker Management Under  Test Project.
4. Then create connector to the Bug tracking system. In our case it is  Jira.
5. On the Issue tracker , give a suitable name.
6. For type, select  Jira (Interface: soap) as we are going to interact with Jira through its SOAP interface.
7. On the configuration page  you need configure the XML as below:

```xml
<!– Template jirasoapInterface –>
<issuetracker>
<username>admin user name </username>
<password>admin user password</password>
<uribase>http://jira url </uribase>
<uriwsdl>http://jira url/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2?wsdl</uriwsdl>
<uriview>http://jira url /browse/</uriview>
<uricreate>http://jira url/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa</uricreate>
</issuetracker>
```

Here  user account need to be  the admin user account you use with jira. Only admin accounts are able to interact with SOAP interface.I didn’t get success with other accounts.  You can get a sample XML file by clicking  ‘show configuration example’.

8. Save this configuration.
9. You can test the Jira integration  by going to the test execution and  select a test case.  That will give the Bug Management Option and through that you can add the relevant Jira Bug ID and access the Jira Bugs directly from the  Testlink window.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can not connect them in a way that you can pass useful date between them.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to attach Jira Bugs to Testlink:

1. Open Jira -> Open the story for which you want to mark execution -> Click on the "QE" tab -> In the Testlink field, enter public URL of testlink story -> Save the changes.
2. Now open Testlink -> Test Execution -> Select the Story -> For every test case there is "Bug Id" field -> Enter the JIRA bug id to that case -> Select Pass/Fail option -> Execute the plan.